# Search bar in Xcode IPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts

I need a help in working with SearchBar in Xcode Iphone. I  have a list of contacts in a tableview. I have a searchbar above it. I diaplay list of contacts. I need to implement search to filter the contacts from the list of contacts. Any help will be of great use to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to save the data, core data?

Comment: Not Clear? Where you are storing contact? How you want to filter the contact? Add some more details.

Comment: Please read the following link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I am using the mobile contacts to display the contact list. I am able to display contacts and select the multi contacts. I am trying to filter the contacts from the contact list. Kindly tell me how can i do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into step by step tutorial [here](http://jduff.github.com/2010/03/01/building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But since i am new to Iphone development, Can you please guide me where is the code to filter the contacts. Like if i type"a" all the names stating with a appears on the screen. How can i achive that.

Comment: Learn the tutorial, you will get the complete understanding. Otherwise you will be beginner for always.