# UISearch in a UITableview Xcode issue

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search bar in Xcode IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510131/search-bar-in-xcode-iphone)

I am working on UISearchBar in Iphone application. I am looking for a simple application to filter the contact list. Any one can please guide me in this issue. I have a Searchbar at the top of the screen. i need a code to implement search in Contacts list.

Kindly guide me in this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You have already asked this question sometime back - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510131/search-bar-in-xcode-iphone

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.


    //mode==1 means search mode.  mode==0 means normal mode.
    if (![searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
        mode=1;
    }

    for (id arrayObject  in listContent)
    {
        NSString *objectInfo=[arrayObject getDescription];
        NSRange result=[objectInfo rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (result.location >= 0 && result.location<=[objectInfo length])
        {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:arrayObject];
        }
    }
}
```